# How to achieve reusable code when doing everything programmatically, without using Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, ipad, ios, code-reuse

I'm the programmatic guy, and I simply don't want to use Interface Builder. I feel out of control, and besides that my GUI is about 90% custom all the time.

Literally every book does everything in Interface Builder and claims that this is the one and only great way to have real MVC going on.

Example: One of those books mentions that programmatically creating an UINavigationController with an Root View Controller and everything else that belongs in there is a big mess and won't be reusable when porting to the iPad, while doing this in XIB is a clever decision. Then the port to iPad using UISplitViewController will be a simple task.

So when I make iPhone apps and want to port those to the iPad too, what strategies work to reuse as much code as possible? I'd like to learn more about how to separate my code and achieve a better overall architectural design without using Interface Builder.

For those who want to tell me I must go with IB: Again, I do a lot of custom UI where IB is often just in the way. And not to mention all the animations. I really have my reasons. For people who make default UI IB is really fine - but please, I don't want to start a fight for IB vs programmatical UI or default UI vs custom UI! It's all about how to achieve great reusable code when doing everything programmatically, and both have their pros and cons.

Comment: Matt Gallagher's minimalist article is a great place to start  http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you did not ask for it, I feel compelled to make the case for why people in general (perhaps not you) should consider IB, and then address the issue of custom components.

I use a lot of animations and custom components.  And I love to use IB...

The key is to use IB for its strengths, and then decide what to do with the rest from there.  What then are the strongest points of IB? Connections, placement, auto-resizing and customizations.

Connections are linking aspects of views and controllers together.  It's faster in IB to drag out a few connections to delegates or references, than it is to write the code that forms the connections.  And, it's a quick place to review all links to the UI you are building.

Placement IB also does well at.  There's a fair amount of code involved in setting up any GGRect correctly.  Not only is it easier to enter and review coordinate and size details in IB, but the tool automatically sizes a lot of elements properly for the container and the control, and offers many guides to help things line up properly - that kind of thing can take a lot of repeated testing to get right.

Related is auto-resizing.  Although I don't feel that many screens can actually have auto-reiszing rules that rotate the screen and come out the other side looking just right (I almost always do rotated views as a separate XIB file), there still are a lot of shifts that can occur in the course of running your application that make it really useful to have these defined just right.  The best example of this is the enlarged status bar while you are on a call.

Lastly comes customization.  This again can be a lot of tedious code to write; try setting up all of the properties on a UILabel manually and it'll have you yearning for quick changes in IB.

With all that said, what is a good approach to custom components?  I like to use UIViews in IB screens, with the class type set to a custom UIView that then fills out the display at runtime.  But at least IB helps me get composition, placement and auto-resizing just right with minimum fuss, and also wire aspects of that custom view into a controller.

The one thing that would really lend IB to use with custom components is if it would simply let me set values for any simple properties the custom view had - then I could adjust parameters like a corner radius or whatever else I had going on.

I urge you to think on IB a little more, as it's a huge productivity boost when used correctly.  There should be nothing about IB that gets in the way, it's there to boost your output.

Answer (score 1):

One book I really liked was Erica Sadun's iPhone Cookbook 1st edition. It did everything programmatically.

Unfortunately the second edition is bloated.

Answer (score 1):

If you reuse lots of your custom UI objects, it would make sense to write a code which

- reads a plist (or a more general XML file) specifying how the custom UI objects should be placed / animated
- and then creates your custom UI objects accordingly.

It's like writing a mini-xib file format tailored to your UI objects; you can also feel that you're in control of everything, as an added bonus.